# where are my minecraft screenshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft screenshots are all missing, I've looked in my `.minecraft` directory and have come up blank. Does anyone know an alternate location?

I do not believe they are in `%appdata%`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Screenshot), your screenshots should be located in `%appdata%/.minecraft/screenshots`. That is if you took a screenshot using the game shortcut ( `F2` on Windows, `FN + F2` on Mac)

If you used the print screen button on your keyboard, the screenshot is copied to the clipboard. You can then paste its content in a software like MS Paint.